# Restarting a failed Luigi Task using a new worker

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, luigi

For some reason (outside of the scope of this question) my python kernel fails at random times while running tasks from my workflow (This happens at times whether or not I am using Luigi to schedule the work). When this happens, Luigi sees the task as failed and attempts to restart it using the same worker, however this will not work because windows has already crashed the kernel for that worker. How do I get Luigi to switch a task to a different worker when an existing worker has failed?

Thanks!